# Plotting 3D vector in qt

Tags: qt, 3d, plot

I would like to make a plot of a 3D vector in QT. Is this possible? And if it is possible how do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean with "plot a 3D vector"? Plotting in the sense of making a diagram? Is this the only vector you want to draw in the entire diagram?

Comment: I would like to have a X,Y,Z grid in which I can plot one unit vector. For example if the value of the vector is (1,0,0), I want to see an 3D-grid (all axis going from -1 to 1) with a line going from (0,0,0) to (1,0,0). Hope this is clear.

Comment: For this you need a helpline at (X,Y,0) (on the "floor") and another line pointing up to the unit vector target point (X,Y,Z). Otherwise you can't distinguish some values from each other. The unit vectors are points on a unit sphere's surface, and from the view of a camera, for each point on the screen there are two possible points on the sphere's surface. Do you see the problem? Another open question is: Do you want it to be drawn perspectively (where far objects appear smaller, typically used in games) or with a parallel projection (typically used for mathematical plots)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at the [QwtPlot3D](http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/web/navigation/feature_frame.html) project.  It is used to plot complex data in an OpenGL context.